# Does .loc[:, ['A','B']] assignment allow to change the dtype of the columns?

Tags: pandas

I was baffled because I could not modify two columns at once using `.loc[:,['A', 'B']` which I guess is because it's returning a copy instead of a view. I cannot find in [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) a definitive guide on when it returns a view and when it returns a copy.

I'm using pandas 0.18 , I can see that in older version of the documentation (pandas 0.13) it used to say "Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector are involved in the indexing operation, the result will be a copy" but I cannot find that in the current documentation

```
pd.__version__
# u'0.18.0'
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3', '4',
                         '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                   'B': ['1', '2', '3', '4',
                         '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                   'C': ['1', '2', '3', '4',
                         '5', '6', '7', '8']})

df.dtypes
    #A    object
    #B    object
    #C    object
    #dtype: object

df2 = df.copy()
df2[['A', 'B']] = df2.loc[:,['A' , 'B']].astype(float) # Works
df2.dtypes
    #A    float64
    #B    float64
    #C     object
    #dtype: object
df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[:,['A', 'B']] = df2.loc[:,['A' , 'B']].astype(float) # Does NOT work
df2.dtypes
    #A    object
    #B    object
    #C    object
    #dtype: object
```

None of those raise a `SettingWithCopy` warning. So I'm a little bit confused of why, the `df2.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]` assignment has no effect.

On closer inspection I do see **that it's not a copy** since in another test, I did assign a dataframe with different values and I they were "saved" in `df2` but the the `dtypes` of the `df2` cannot be "set" via the `.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]` assignment.

Is there any reason why `.loc[:, ['A', 'B']] =` assignment doesn't not change dtypes and `[['A', 'B']] =` does?

Comment: This looks like a bug, the behaviour is the same in `0.18.1` and the `dtypes` is incorrectly not being set, if you look at `df2['A'].iloc[0]` you will see that it is indeed `float` dtype as are all the elements `df2['A'].apply(lambda x: print(type(x)))` it could be that since we are using the new indexers, it's taking some kinda position that it may not be sure if all rows are being modified so it preserves the original dtype but that is a guess

Comment: Also `for c in ['A', 'B']: df2.loc[:, c] = df2.loc[:, c].astype(float)`  works, but that assigns `pd.Series` one by one instead of all full `DataFrame`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was actually just a [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13260) and [doc note](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#astype) added about this.

> When trying to convert a subset of columns to a specified type using `astype()` and `loc()`, upcasting occurs.
>
> `loc()` tries to fit in what we are assigning to the current dtypes, while `[]` will overwrite them taking the dtype from the right hand side.

Basically, `.loc` tries to cast back to the original dtype on assignment, where `[]` does not.  It's the expected behavior, but a bit subtle.