# Issue setting entire column (and changing dtype) with .loc[:,'col'] in pandas 1.5+

Tags: python, pandas, casting, in-place, pandas-loc

I often use `df.loc[:,'col'] = arr` to reassign columns rather than `df['col'] = arr`. This was a recommended practice to avoid the fact that, prior to Copy-on-Write changes in pandas 2.0, we couldn't guarantee whether a view of copy was returned in various cases, and using `df['col']` can sometimes lead to accidental chained assignments and the infamous SettingWithCopyWarning [[example]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

However, since the [changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html) to inplace operation when setting with .loc and .iloc were implemented in pandas 1.5.0, I've had inconsistent behaviors using `df.loc[:,'col'] = new_arr` where the code will execute without any warnings or errors, but the column type is not modified as expected when trying to cast a column to a different datatype.

For example, I have a dataframe weather_df, which reads in the 'year' column with a dtype of 'float64' (there are missing values that default to NaN).

```
import pandas as pd
weather_df = pd.read_csv(weather_file)
```

I want to fill missing values with 0, and cast the column dtype to 'int32' instead.

The following code executes silently, and replaces the NaN values with 0, but *does not* modify the type (weather_df['year].dtype remains float64) for pandas 1.5+:

```
weather_df.loc[:,'year'] = weather_df['year'].fillna(0).astype('int32')
```

Frustratingly, the following code *does* modify the datatype of the weather_df 'year' column values in pandas 1.5+, despite previously being not recommended practice:

```
weather_df['year'] = weather_df['year'].fillna(0).astype('int32')
```

Before the recent changes (1.-1.4), both of these lines made equivalent updates to weather_df. My understanding from the documentation was that both of these lines should continue to work since I am setting the entire column. It should try to do the operation in place first, then fall back to casting when the in-place operation fails due to mismatching types (only because I am replacing the entire column), but that is not happening for `.loc[:,'col']`.

The following simplified example reproduces the problem for me...

#### Version 1.?-1.4

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[20.,19.5,21.,24.,23.,22.], 'col2':[2020.,2021.,2022.,2023.,np.nan,2019.]})
>>> print(df['col2'].dtype)
float64
>>> df.loc[:,'col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')
>>> print(df['col2'].dtype)
**int32**
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[20.,19.5,21.,24.,23.,22.], 'col2':[2020.,2021.,2022.,2023.,np.nan,2019.]})
>>> df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')
>>> print(df['col2'].dtype)
int32
```

#### Version 1.5+

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[20.,19.5,21.,24.,23.,22.], 'col2':[2020.,2021.,2022.,2023.,np.nan,2019.]})
>>> print(df['col2'].dtype)
float64
>>> df.loc[:,'col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')
>>> print(df['col2'].dtype)
**float64**
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[20.,19.5,21.,24.,23.,22.], 'col2':[2020.,2021.,2022.,2023.,np.nan,2019.]})
>>> df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')
>>> print(df['col2'].dtype)
int32
```

Is this the intended behavior from now on, or is this a bug? Is there a workaround to use `.loc` and get the old behavior, or should I just forget the old advice about using `.loc` to avoid chained assignments?

Edit: I am running this on Linux x86_64 using Python version 3.8.3, and the error occurs for any version 1.5.0 to 2.0.3 (latest). I've also clarified that fillna seems to work in both cases, but the typecast does not work using `.loc`.

Second edit: I have further clarified that this is *not* a post about the SettingWithCopyWarning. No warnings are raised by the example code. It's just that pandas 1.5+ causes the behavior of the two lines to diverge (because `df.loc[:,'col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')` no longer changes the dtype of 'col2', as was the case before pandas version 1.5. With pandas version 1.something to 1.4, the second print statement of the example code will change to 'int32'. This could cause bugs (as it did for me) for anyone updating pandas from an older version.

Comment: Does Pandas 1.5+ include Pandas 2.0 and later? Or just the 1.x series?

Comment: I don't see this behaviour for either 1.4 or 1.5. For 2.1, I get some funny result: the NaN is replaced by 0, but the type remains float64. If I use `weather['year'] = weather['year'].fillna(0).astype('int32')`, which seems the more obvious thing to use, for all versions (1.4, 1.5 and 2.1), I do not get a deprecation warning, and I get the expected result. Perhaps my toy model is incorrect, but I can't reproduce your results. This is for Python 3.11 on macOS.

Comment: Since I can't reproduce your results, could you 1/ list your Python version and OS? And 2/ either provide some example data (in code), or provide the "weather_file". This way, your problem may become more reproducible.

Comment: The behavior you described for version 2.1: "the NaN is replaced by 0, but the type remains float64" is exactly the behavior I am seeing as well. I've updated the post to reflect this fact. The original DataFrame *is* modified, but only by fillna. The type does not change as expected using .loc[].

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the same behavior on Windows 10 and 11 using pandas 2.0.3 on Python 3.8. Setting with .loc[:,'col'] operates in place, and fillna works as expected, but the assignment ignores the typecast. The version this change is reflected in may be different for macOS, but this update was made somewhere along the way and does not seem intentional based on the documentation.

Comment: The core issue may be that you should use `df['name'] = df['name'].fillna(0).astype('int32')`, and not use `.loc`. You don't show actual code that causes the warning shown at the top. I've tried your example code with Pandas 1.4, 1.5 and 2.0, with the third line replaced by `df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')`, and I get no such warning at all, and the correct behaviour. There is no need for using `.loc`, and I don't think it should be used. Thus my gut feeling is that you get this warning for another reason, and that led you astray to use  `.loc`, while it isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. There is no SettingWithCopy warning from the example code here. I was just noting that the SettingWithCopy warning encourages users to use `.loc` when setting instead of slicing with `[]`, which *can* inconsistently lead to chained assignments (see [here](https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/) or the many posts on the topic). Other than that side-note, this post has nothing to do with the SettingWithCopy warning.

Comment: Previously, `df.loc[:,'col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(0).astype('int32')` would result in a `df['col2'].dtype` of `int32`. On versions of pandas above 1.5, it will result in `float64` as I've shown in my example. That change does *not* produce any warnings. I only noticed it when it introduced a bug later on in my code, which is what prompted me to investigate and make this post. And you are right that the solution is to use `df['col']`, but my point is that `df.loc[:,'col']` works for every other assignment. Why should it have this subtlety different interaction with the `astype()` function?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle note about this in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#astype) under astype():

> When trying to convert a subset of columns to a specified type using
> `astype()` and `loc()`, upcasting occurs.
>
> `loc()` tries to fit in what we are assigning to the current dtypes,
> while `[]` will overwrite them taking the dtype from the right hand
> side.

The same issue was raised for older versions of pandas (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619314/does-loc-a-b-assignment-allow-to-change-the-dtype-of-the-columns) about pandas 0.18). At some point (I have not been able to identify when), this was changed such that `df.loc[:,'col']` and `df['col']` produced the same result when using .astype() to cast a column to a new type. I know this because pandas versions 1.2-1.4 (at least) produce the result I expected where `df['col'].dtype` was updated regardless of whether `df.loc[:,'col']` or `df['col']` was used on the left hand side of the assignment.

However, with pandas version 1.5-2.0.3 (Windows/Linux, Python 3.8), this changed again such that the `loc()` and `astype()` interaction follows the note in the docs (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121697/why-does-converting-a-column-from-datetime-to-string-in-pandas-not-work-using-l?noredirect=1&lq=1) regarding pandas 2.0.0).

In general, unless you are trying to cast your column to a new datatype using `astype()`, you can use `loc()` with a row mask of `:` to make assignments, but for type casting you will need to use `[]` for now.

I feel like this behavior should raise a warning to inform the user that the intended typecast fails using `.loc[]`. I will raise an issue on the pandas-dev GitHub and update this answer with a link.