Why does df.loc[:, cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category') fail to cast dtype to category?
If I do
df.loc[:, cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category')

to cast the object datatype to category, then the dtype of the column remains as object, but the following works as expected:
df[cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category')

However, based on my understanding, df.loc[:, cat_col] should modify the types in place, whereas df[cat_col] returns a view, which may lead to a chained assignment issue.
Can someone explain why using df.loc[:, cat_col] doesn't successfully cast the dtype to category, while using df[cat_col] does?
Example:
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame with object type columns
data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'John', 'Alice'],
    'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'New York', 'London'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 28, 32],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df.dtypes)
print()

# Convert object type column to categorical using df.loc[:, cat_col]
cat_col = 'Name'
df.loc[:, cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category')
print("DataFrame after converting object to categorical using df.loc[:, cat_col]:")
print(df.dtypes)
print()

# Convert object type column to categorical using df[cat_col]
cat_col = 'City'
df[cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category')
print("DataFrame after converting object to categorical using df[cat_col]:")
print(df.dtypes)

In this example, when we try to convert the 'Name' column to categorical using df.loc[:, cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category'), the dtype of the 'Name' column remains as object.
However, when we convert the 'City' column to categorical using df[cat_col] = df[cat_col].astype('category'), it successfully casts the dtype to category.
This behavior is unexpected because df.loc[:, cat_col] should modify the types in place, whereas df[cat_col] returns a view, which may lead to a chained assignment issue.
Can someone explain the reason behind this behavior and provide insights on the correct way to convert object type columns to categorical in a DataFrame?

This seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536875/issue-setting-entire-column-and-changing-dtype-with-loc-col-in-pandas-1

As per the suggested duplicate: "In version 2.0.x, df.loc[:, foo] = bar will only change the dtype, when necessary."
